# How to Remove the Blue Lock Icon on my VB6 Form?

Tags: vb6

I created forms and functions in a draft project. When it was time to put it to the final project, I tried adding my files but a blue lock icon appeared just on the left of my file. Now I cannot edit my forms.

I need to get rid of the lock so I can edit. The worse part is, my VB6 is in Japanese so I do not know where to look for properties. Please help!

Comment: Usually means the files are read-only on the disk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyway, I solved it already. I imported it first and maybe that's what prompted the VB6 to have the forms locked because they were created in a different project. I edited it using the draft project and copy-pasted the edited files to the Final Project's folder. This time, the blue lock disappeared.